# How do I fix an error in my equation involving resize?

Tags: amsmath, resize, amsfonts

How do I adjust

```
\begin{align}
\resizebox{.9\hsize}{!}{$\displaystyle{\inf \lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=
\left\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
\bigg[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(S\capI_{k,\epsilon}))\bigg]}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
\bigg[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigg]}:
S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k,\epsilon},
A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}J_{k,\epsilon} \right\}}$}
\end{align}\\
```

to avoid errors. Currently, my preview page is blank.

Here are all the packages I used

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Why do you have to resize? It produces inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: You should avoid resizing but if you do this there is no possibility of alignment so you should use equation not align.

Comment: please always post a complete small docuemnt that shows the problem, don't post disconnected fragments

Comment: there are several things that are bad style that will produce poor output but the only error is `\capI` undefined as you intended `\cap I`

Answer (score 1):

Resizing material is dangerous; leave the problem to the final revision, when you're sure that the text is in final form.

A couple of notes on your input: `\bigg` should be either `\biggl` or `\biggr` (for *left*, opening, and *right*, closing), but here it is too large: a simple `\bigl`–`\bigr` pair does the job better.

In order to apply `\small` or `\footnotesize` it's better to use a box inside the `equation` environment, or the line spacing around the display could be uneven.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx,varwidth}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Equation\eqref{small} has been typeset in \verb|\small| size; depending
on your text width you may not need the \verb|\hspace| instructions,
which are needed here to avoid the equation number is moved down.
In equation\eqref{footnotesize}, there should be no need for tricks.

\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{equation}\label{small}
\hspace{-0.5em}
\mbox{\small$\displaystyle
  \inf \lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=
  \left\{
    \frac{
      \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
      \bigl[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]
    }{
      \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
      \bigl[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]
    }
    :
    S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k,\epsilon},
    A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}J_{k,\epsilon}
  \right\}
$}
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{equation}\label{footnotesize}
\mbox{\footnotesize$\displaystyle
  \inf \lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=
  \left\{
    \frac{
      \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
      \bigl[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]
    }{
      \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
      \bigl[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]
    }
    :
    S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k,\epsilon},
    A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}J_{k,\epsilon}
  \right\}
$}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\resizebox{.9\hsize}{!}{$\displaystyle{\inf \lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=
\left\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
\bigg[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(S\capI_{k,\epsilon}))\bigg]}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
\bigg[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigg]}:
S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k,\epsilon},
A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}J_{k,\epsilon} \right\}}$}
\end{align}\\
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...n }) \bigg [1-\mu (A)(1-\mu (S\capI 
                                                  _{k,\epsilon }))\bigg ]
l.13 \end{align}
                \\
? 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 13--14
```

So the only error is `\capI` which should be `\cap I` and a warning from the misplaced `\\`  after `\end{align}`.

However you should use `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` not `\big`  and `align` is doing nothing here as you have no alignment specified.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\inf \lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=\\
\left\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
\biggl[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\biggr]}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
\biggl[1-\mu(A)(1-\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\biggr]}:
S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k,\epsilon},
A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}J_{k,\epsilon} \right\}
\end{multline}

Or if you really must fit on one line
{\small\begin{equation}
\inf \lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=
\left\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
\bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
\bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]}:
S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k,\epsilon},
A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}J_{k,\epsilon} \right\}
\end{equation}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the display with `\small` is preceded by multi-line text, be sure to check the baselines -- they can be reduced so the lines are closer together than they should be.  If that happens, ask another question.